# Redirect to homepage if file not found for specific directory

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm stuck on `.htaccess`.

Link:

```
www.example.com/assets/images/abc.png
```

whenever `abc.png` exists in this `/assets/images` directory then preview image in browser. But if I delete `abc.png` image from this directory, it will redirect 404 not found page but I want to redirect to homepage (root url : `www.example.com`)

I want like this : whenever image file not exist for specific `/assets/images` folder. It should redirect to the home page.

I tried this but not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#If the file does not exist assets/images folder it will redirect on homepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is an *internal rewrite*, not a "redirect". But the condition you used *excluded* the `/assets/images` subdirectory (using the `!` prefix), so it applies to all other directories except the one you want!

Try something like the following instead at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# If an image does not exist in /assets/images then redirect to homepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^assets/images/[\w/-]+\.(png|jpg|gif)$ / [R=302,L]
```

All the pattern matching for the URL is performed in the `RewriteRule` directive - no need to use a separate condition. So only requests that look-like images are tested.

No need for the directory check, since I assume you don't have directories that look like image filenames.

This allows for multiple subdirectories within `/assets/images`. eg. `/assets/images/foo/bar/abc.png`. If all your images are contained directly inside `/assets/images` then you can remove the slash from the character class `[\w/-]`.

It also assumes that subdirectories and filenames can only consist of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen).

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

HOWEVER, this redirect only makes sense if images are requested directly in the browser. If they are embedded in an HTML `img` element then a redirect will simply be seen as a broken image, unless your homepage actually returns an image?!

Answer (score 0):

in app/Exceptions/Handler.php file

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if($this->isHttpException($e))
        {
            switch ($e->getStatusCode()) 
                {
                // not found
                case 404:
                return redirect()->guest('home');
                break;

                // internal error
                case '500':
                return redirect()->guest('home');
                break;

                default:
                    return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this render function will work for whole project and if any link not work or not found then redirect to homepage as per your answer. but, i want to redirect on homepage whenever  user will hit link with image path in url directly in browser and if file does not exist on that specific folder then it should be redirect to homepage.

Comment: In that case try this.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Add additional file extensions to the list as needed.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|tiff)$
RewriteRule (.*) /relative/location/of/errorimage.jpg

this is for image kind of files.

Comment: It generates 500 Internal Server

Comment: /relative/location/of/errorimage.jpg

hope you have changed this path to URL ?

Comment: you can write a helper in that case.
to check that the file exists or not (while clicking).

if exists, the helper will pass away else redirect to home route.

Alternatively

while fetching the image you can check that the file exists, if exists then provide the file url else the home url.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

refer this link for more information.
this may help.